# Huawei Matebook D16 Ubuntu 20.04LTS no sound problem

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Problem: I never heard any sound from my device.

`inxi -SMA` outputs

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor 
  driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-43-generic
```

`aplay -l` outputs

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`sudo lspci` outputs

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device 1001 (rev 03)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
```

`sudo lspci -v` outputs

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ -2147483648
    Capabilities: [40] Secure device <?>
    Capabilities: [64] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [74] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: d0500000-d05fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000450200000-00000004503fffff [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [400] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [440] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: d0400000-d04fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [400] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [440] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: d0000000-d03fffff [size=4M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000000fce0000000-000000fcf01fffff [size=258M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [400] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [440] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 70
    Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device 1001 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Silicon Motion, Inc. Device 2262
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39, NUMA node 0
    Memory at d0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at fce0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fcf0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [400] Data Link Feature <?>
    Capabilities: [410] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [440] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu

03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 86
    Memory at d03c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67
    Memory at d0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at d03c4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=2 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp

03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1 (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41
    Memory at d0100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e30
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66
    Memory at d0380000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x
```

`uname -a` outputs

```
Linux UbuntuOzan 5.11.0-43-generic #47~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 13 11:06:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`alsamixer`
[image]
[image]

In Sound Settings HDMI/DisplayPort-HDAudio Generic is the only option

I tried more solutions than below.

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
sudo alsa force-reload
alsamixer -c 1
sudo adduser ubuntuozan audio
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0 into it.

Thanks in advance for any help.